# How to get list of Named range,sheet name and referance formuls using XSSF and SAX (Event API) for large excel file

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm tring to to read large excel file (size~10MB,.xlsx) .

I'm using below code

```
Workbook xmlworkbook =WorkbookFactory.create(OPCPackage.openOrCreate(root_path_name_file));
```

But it's showing Heap memory issue.

I have also seen other solution on StackOverflow some of them given to increase the JVM but i dont want to increase jvm.

Issue 1) We can't use `SXSSF (Streaming Usermodel API)` because this is only for writing or creating new workbook.

My sole objective to get the number of NamedRange of sheet, Total number of sheet and their sheet name for large excel file.

Answer (score 6):

If the requirement is only to get the named ranges and sheet names, then only the `/xl/workbook.xml` from the `*.xlsx` `ZIPPackage` must be parsed since those informations are all stored there.

This is possible by getting the appropriate `PackagePart` and parsing the `XML` from this. For parsing `XML` my favorite is using `StAX`.

Example code which gets all sheet names and defined named ranges:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Characters;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.io.File;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class StaxReadOPCPackageParts {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   File file = new File("file.xlsx");
   OPCPackage opcpackage = OPCPackage.open(file);

   //get the workbook package part
   PackagePart workbookpart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/workbook.xml")).get(0);

   //create reader for package part            
   XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(workbookpart.getInputStream());

   List<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<>();
   Map<String, String> definedNames = new HashMap<>();

   boolean isInDefinedName = false;
   String sheetName = "";
   String definedNameName = "";
   StringBuffer definedNameFormula = new StringBuffer();

   while(reader.hasNext()){ //loop over all XML in workbook.xml
    XMLEvent event = (XMLEvent)reader.next();

    if(event.isStartElement()) {
     StartElement startElement = (StartElement)event;
     QName startElementName = startElement.getName();
     if(startElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("sheet")) { //start element of sheet definition
      Attribute attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("name"));
      sheetName = attribute.getValue();
      sheetNames.add(sheetName);
     } else if (startElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("definedName")) { //start element of definedName
      Attribute attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("name"));
      definedNameName = attribute.getValue();
      isInDefinedName = true;
     }
    } else if(event.isCharacters() && isInDefinedName) { //character content of definedName == the formula
     definedNameFormula.append(((Characters)event).getData());
    } else if(event.isEndElement()) {
     EndElement endElement = (EndElement)event;
     QName endElementName = endElement.getName();
     if(endElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("definedName")) { //end element of definedName
      definedNames.put(definedNameName, definedNameFormula.toString());
      definedNameFormula = new StringBuffer();
      isInDefinedName = false;
     }
    }

   } 

   opcpackage.close();

   System.out.println("Sheet names:");
   for (String shName : sheetNames) {
    System.out.println("Sheet name: " + shName);
   }

   System.out.println("Named ranges:");
   for (String defName : definedNames.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + defName + ", Formula: " + definedNames.get(defName));
   }

  } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine.Can i read data using this concept ??Actually i need to only read the Excel file and want to open file in read mode .If there is any other methods please suggest

Comment: For only reading the sheet contents actually [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#XSSF+and+SAX+%28Event+API%29) is provided by `apache poi`.  Have you tried this? If you have, what is the problem you are having with this approach? Surely you can also read `/xl/worksheets/sheetN.xml` parts using the `StAX` approach. But this is then another question and should not be handled into this question.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter I found your answers regarding Apache POI very insightful. Could you please let me know if there is a memory efficient way to append to .xls files. (Client is very insistent on .xls file for the report and I did all possible research but in vain)
All I could find is that to append to existing .xls, we first have to load the entire file into memory, append data and then write it back. Is that the only way ?