# Get excel sheet names for large excel files using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have the following code that I use to get the sheet names of an excel file(.xlsx)

```
    XSSFWorkbook workBookXlsx = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(pathToFile));
    ArrayList<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<>();

    int numberOfSheets = workBookXlsx.getNumberOfSheets();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
        sheetNames.add(workBookXlsx.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName());
    }

    workBookXlsx = null;
```

The issue I have with the above code is that it takes a lot of memory(~700MB) & a long time(5-6s) to create the `XSSFWorkbook` for a file of size 9MB. Even setting the `workBookXlsx` to `null` doesn't release the memory taken by the `javaw`(I know `gc` may or maynot be called & JVM wont release memory just because I have set a variable to null)

I did go through the documentation of [Workbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html), [XSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) & from what I understood, there is no method that will help me get the sheet names with low memory imprint.

The one solution I have found is to manually unzip the `.xlsx` file and read the contents of the `.\xl\woorkbook.xml` to get the sheet names and the `r:id`

Is there an API for getting the sheet names in an `.xlsx` file without large memory imprint?

Comment: Why not use the low-level [SAX-based API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) and skip the sheet processing step?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363139/how-to-get-list-of-named-range-sheet-name-and-referance-formuls-using-xssf-and-s/46364250#46364250

Comment: @Gagravarr There are many sheets, so first the sheet has to be selected and then I do use SAX parser.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanx. I never got that link while googling. To conclude I have to manually read the workbook.xml. I will upvote your answer. It would be useful for others in future if you can commit that solution to Apache POI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show what @Gagravarr probably meant with his comment:

The [XSSFReader](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.html) contains a method [XSSFReader.getSheetsData](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.html#getSheetsData--) which "Returns an Iterator which will let you get at all the different Sheets in turn. Each sheet's InputStream is only opened when fetched from the Iterator. It's up to you to close the InputStreams when done with each one.". But as often this is not the whole truth. In truth it returns a [XSSFReader.SheetIterator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.SheetIterator.html) which has a method [XSSFReader.SheetIterator.getSheetName](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.SheetIterator.html#getSheetName--) to get the sheet names.

Example:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class ExcelXSSFGetSheetNamesXSSFReader {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream("Example.xlsx"));
  XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
  Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();

  if (sheets instanceof XSSFReader.SheetIterator) {
   XSSFReader.SheetIterator sheetiterator = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator)sheets;

   while (sheetiterator.hasNext()) {
    InputStream dummy = sheetiterator.next();

    System.out.println(sheetiterator.getSheetName());

    dummy.close();
   }
  }

  pkg.close();
 }
}
```

Conclusion: Currently you cannot work with `apache poi` only by trusting the API documentation. Instead you must always have a look at the [source code](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.java?view=markup#l187).

Comment: This actually worked faster but with more memory imprint than the other link you shared. This code took like ~2s while the other code took around ~7s for the same file.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter I found your answers regarding Apache POI very insightful. Could you please let me know if there is a memory efficient way to append to .xls files. (Client is very insistent on .xls file for the report and I did all possible research but in vain)
All I could find is that to append to existing .xls, we first have to load the entire file into memory, append data and then write it back. Is that the only way ?