# Excel Sheet names in Apache POI (without "user" model)

Tags: apache-poi

I need to quickly scan a large number of workbooks, which can be done with

```
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader(pkg);
    SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();
    Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();
```

However, in Excel .xlsx files, the sheet names are not in the sheet XML.  They are doubly indirect of a _rels structure for reasons best known to Microsoft.

So how does one get them in poi?

The following works, but is very slow.  E.g. goes from 4 seconds to 19 seconds to scan a 7 meg workbook.

```
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
        for (int sx=0; sx<wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sx++) {
            System.out.println("Sheet: " + sx + " " + wb.getSheetName(sx));
        }
```

So how does one do it efficiently?  And if inefficient, is the order of the sheets the same in both approaches?

(POI itself was very useful for the .xls binary format.  For the .xlsx one could almost be better off just opening the zip and handling the XML raw.  But thanks to the POI team for providing it.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453102/get-excel-sheet-names-for-large-excel-files-using-apache-poi/47483170#47483170

Comment: Btw.: " For the .xlsx one could almost be better off just opening the zip and handling the XML raw": Then why not just doing that? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363139/how-to-get-list-of-named-range-sheet-name-and-referance-formuls-using-xssf-and-s/46364250#46364250.

Comment: Call [XSSFReader.getWorkbookData()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.html#getWorkbookData--), and either process that directly, or hand it off to XMLBeans to read? That has your sheet names in